# Synthetic solution needed: What is $\angle MBC$?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Consider $\Delta ABC$ and a point $M$ in its interior so that $\angle MAB = 10^{\circ}, \angle MBA = 20^{\circ}, \angle MCA =30^{\circ}$ and $\angle MAC = 40^{\circ}$. What is $\angle MBC$?

I actually got a solution, with trig with answer $60$. However can someone give a pure synthetic solution?

Comment: See if this answers your question - https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2p2

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps. I happen to write in my blog. Anyways!

Walkthrough: a. Take $D$ as a point on $CM$ such that $\angle DAC=30^{\circ}$, and define $BD\cap AC=E$. So $\Delta DAC$ is isosceles.

b. Show M is the incentre of $\Delta ABD$

c. Show $\angle EDC=60^{\circ}$.

d. Show $\Delta BAC$ is isosceles .

e. So $\boxed{\angle MBC=60^{\circ}}. $

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an idea behind "Show M is the incentre of ΔAMD"?

Comment: @user $\angle BMD=90+\frac{\angle BAD}{2}$ and then angle bisector property

Comment: Then probably you mean $\triangle ABD$.

Comment: @user yes , a typo